# What is the meaning of לֵאמֹר?

Tags: words, tanach

What is the meaning of לֵאמֹר?

In all the usage of לֵאמֹר in the Torah, it almost seems unnecessary to add the word "to say" or "saying". For example, here is the first occurrence:

וַיְבָרֶךְ אֹתָם אֱלֹהִים, לֵאמֹר:

Knowing that no words in the Torah are unnecessary makes it more intriguing to me to find out what the real meaning of this word is.

Comment: It introduces a direct quote. A midrashic explanation (sometimes brought by Rashi) explains it as "to say to someone else." In later Hebrew the same function was served by ואמר (e.g. "מכריז ואומר")

Comment: Levinas said that his teacher, Monsieur Chouchani, knew 120 explanations of the word לאמר, and only revealed one to him.

Comment: @Josh please put a link here.

Comment: @ba Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @ba include source and links.

Comment: @ba what is the difference between your comment and the answer below by Meir?

Comment: @ninamag I think Meir is giving a different midrashic explanation. He gives one source for what I wrote in his comment to his answer. I unfortunately don't have time right now to expand what I wrote with sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sifra at the beginning of Vayikra writes that the word ‘leimor’ should be understood as ‘in order to say’, i.e. in order to repeat over to the Jewish People.

The Ramban in Shemos, 6, 10, brings this explanation but points out that it does not work in all cases. He therefore states, “What is correct in my eyes is that the word ‘leimor’ is to indicate clarification of the matter in all places, and God spoke to Moshe in a complete statement and not a doubtful statement, and not hinting any matters.”

HaKesav VeHaKabbalah argues that there are cases where the Ramban’s explanation also doesn’t work such as Lemech calling his son Noach (Bereishis 5, 29) then adding “leimor…” and cites a few other examples such as the beginning of the Aseres Hadibros (Ten Commandments) where the word leimor is used, though it seems superfluous to say ‘with clarity’. In Shemos 20, 1, he therefore takes the Ramban's idea a bit further and says that the word leimor comes to indicate further explanation and details given over. I.e. the word ‘vayedaber’ or ‘vayomer’ would mean to explain the kelalim - the general principles, and ‘leimor’ would mean to explain the peratim - the finer details of the mitzvos. In Vayikra 1, 1, he gives a similar explanation that the word ‘amirah’ in general (and as used in the word leimor) is to indicate greater depth of understanding. He cites the Vilna Gaon who said that ‘dibur’ is the statement of the Torah as it is written before us, while ‘amirah’ is the inner depth of the Torah and its intent and rationale. At his conclusion, he also cites Naftali Hertz Weisel who understood these words to mean the opposite - dibur (vayedaber) is used to indicate the Torah sheb’al peh, whereas amirah (leimor) is used for Torah shebichsav.

Sifra, Vayikra - see “davar acher…” (sorry, you'll have to copy & paste this link) -
https://www.sefaria.org/Sifra,_Vayikra_Dibbura_d'Nedavah,_Chapter_2.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Ramban, Shemos 6, 10 - https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Exodus.6.10.1/en/Sefaria_Community_Translation?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

HaKesav VeHaKabbalah, Shemos 20, 1 - https://www.sefaria.org/HaKtav_VeHaKabalah,_Exodus.20.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

HaKesav VeHaKabbalah, Vayikra, 1, 1 - https://www.sefaria.org/HaKtav_VeHaKabalah,_Leviticus.1.1.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @Alter_Bochur, please include links.

Comment: “What is correct in my eyes is that the word ‘leimor’ is to indicate clarification ..." - So, in place of "leimor", I can read it as, "for review", or "for clarification", or "for  clarity", or "for discussion"?

Comment: @mevaqesh I would appreciate your input on this answer, because you had previously commented on an answer on this same posting of mine. Thanks.

Comment: @ninamag according to the Ramban you could substitute the word 'leimor' with 'clearly'. I.e. 'And Hashem spoke to Moshe clearly', or 'Speak to the Children of Israel clearly'.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. What is the Hebrew word that Ramba"n used for "clearly"?

Comment: @ninamag He uses the word ברורה in his description.

Comment: So when I come across לֵאמֹר  I can also read it as לֵברור , to mean "for clarity" or "with clarity"?

Comment: @ninamag According to the Ramban you would read לֵאמֹר  as "with clarity".

Answer (score 1):

[Yoma 4b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.4b.11?lang=he) says that it is a grant of permission to tell it over to others (without that, it would have been meant only for the listener's ears):

> אמר ר' (מוסיא בר בריה דרבי מסיא משמיה דר' מוסיא) רבה מניין לאומר דבר לחבירו שהוא בבל יאמר עד שיאמר לו לך אמור שנאמר (ויקרא א, א) וידבר ה' אליו מאהל מועד לאמר

Comment: Can you make a rough translation of the Hebrew.

Comment: @ninamag This post mistakenly assumes that Talmudic homiletics necessarily correspond to words' actual meanings, and then conflates the message of the passage with the literal intent of the word. The passage states (Soncino translation): R. Hanina said: No man
shall speak to his neighbour unless he calls him first to speak to him. Rabbah said: Whence do we
know that if a man had said something to his neighbour the latter must not spread the news without
the informant's telling him ‘Go and say it’? From the scriptural text: The Lord spoke to him out of
the tent of meeting, lemor [saying]".

Comment: [cont.] The passage never claims that the meaning of the word (which is what you asked about) is the granting of permission to others. Rather, this homily is based on the understanding that implicit in the term is a permission to relate it. || Importantly it does *not* state, as this post suggests that every usage of the term is _for this purpose_. The most that one could infer from this _derash_ is that this would be implicit in every usage; not that that is the meaning of every usage, or the point of the term in every usage.

Comment: @mevaqesh thanks. a few moments later, it actually says that "lemor" is a contraction of "lo omer", do not say.

Comment: @Meir why does Yoma 4b:11 says that "Lemor is a contraction of lo emor, meaning: Do not say"?

Comment: @ninamag the Gemara there doesn't say that; Rashi does. I don't know if he means that it's actually a contraction, or just that the very fact that it has to add לאמר, "to say," means that without that it would be forbidden to say it to someone else.

Comment: @ninamag your understanding of Rashi seems to be correct. See for example Temurah 7b.

Comment: @Meir What is the difference between your answer and the following comment, "It introduces a direct quote. A midrashic explanation (sometimes brought by Rashi) explains it as "to say to someone else." In later Hebrew the same function was served by ואמר (e.g. "מכריז ואומר") – b a Sep 15 at 9:29"? Thanks.

Comment: @ninamag I assume you mean what he cited as "a midrashic explanation"? Can't speak for him, but I'd say that he means one side of it - "go out and tell them this" (as in Rashi to Vayikra 1:1), and the Gemara I quoted is giving the other side: "*this* I want you to convey to them, but not necessarily other things that I tell you."